# What is httpBody in NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, request, nsurlconnection

I need to create request manually, not using AFNetworking.

```
NSString *baseURL = @"http://pl-dev2.railwaymen.org:4213/";
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"events/%@", identifier];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:baseURL];
//final URL: http://pl-dev2.railwaymen.org:4213/events/6572673456

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
```

Now I want to send some parameters:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
    "a": "valueA", 
    "b": 23, 
    "c": [NSNull null], 
    "d": ["lisbona", "warsaw", "ny"], 
    "e": UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
};
```

1. How do I do that?

   ```
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:nil error:&error];
   NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   [request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```

   Unfortunately it **doesnt work**
2. How looks the final request URL?

   ```
   http://pl-dev2.railwaymen.org:4213/events/6572673456?a=valueA&b=23&c=&d[]=lisbona&d[]=warsaw&d[]=ny&e=
   ```
3. Which part of that query is httpBody? Every after `?`.
4. What about parameters `c` and `e`?
5. How it works?

Comment: Insert  jsonString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)jsonString,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));     in front of setHTTPBody: method.

Comment: your code look fine but don't send [NSNull null] and NSdata * UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) in body parameters. remove parameter 'c' if it's nil, and 'e' need to bee something like NSString of data encodebase64 or String of imageURL

Comment: no, I have to send `nil` parameter, because it means to clear sth on the server side, no parameter means to do nothing with it. How to send `NSData`? I need to send an image in my example.

Comment: common you can't send NSData with metadata via http body params. if send NSData to server with metadata you need use something like multipart-upload or resumable upload. Or first upload NSData and send only link. Or convert NSData to NSString with encodebase64, and in server decode to get data

Comment: How to use multipart upload, does UIKit API have sth like that? Can you show me an example?

Comment: read more about multipart upload at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#multipart . You need to create data in multipart format then send to server via httpBody

Comment: is there a documentation with objc examples or swift?

Comment: yes it's not depend in programing language